# Why can't we define struct pointers to null in the beginning

Tags: c, struct

Why can't we define a struct pointer to null in the beginning. I always have to declare a struct pointer to null in my program.

Wouldn't it be hassle free to point those to null at the start & why does it cause some bugs in the end ?

```
struct qwe
{
  int data;
  struct qwe *next=NULL;
};
```

or this way

```
struct qwe
{
  int data;
  struct qwe *next;
  next=NULL;
};
```

I am using C language & I get errors when I do it this way;

verify.c:8:22: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    struct node *next=NULL;

these are the errors

```
jharvard@appliance (~): make verify
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror    verify.c  -lcs50 -lm -o verify
verify.c:9:5: error: type name requires a specifier or qualifier
next=NULL;

verify.c:9:5: error: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-int]
next=NULL;

verify.c:9:5: error: duplicate member 'next'

verify.c:8:18: note: previous declaration is here
struct node *next;
             ^
verify.c:9:9: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
next=NULL;
```

Comment: Yes, you can't. Sorry that's syntax, little bit too opinion based to be discussed on SO! BTW if your second option is what you want why don't you move to C++? There you have a constructor and a new operator...

Comment: If you want to use a language other than C, by all means write it.  However, C does not define such a facility (and there are lots of other things that would be preferable additions to C before that one came up for discussion — all else apart, why limit it to pointers?).

Comment: Oh...how can I learn to change the syntax ?

Comment: The suggestion was that you write a new language — it wouldn't be (pure) C. One possibility would take either GCC or LLVM/clang source code and modify it to support your extension to C.  You could then advocate for its adoption into C, based on wide experience of your new feature and its self-evident desirability to people who've been using C for many years and have written the compilers etc.  If you're successful (don't hold your breath), then you end up helping craft a new revision of the standard.  As it stands, I think that it has a very small chance of obtaining any widespread support.

Comment: wow I didn't know there was so much to it. So, lastly, suppose I'd like to change this, which subject do I need to learn efficiently ? may be compiler design ? @JonathanLeffler Thanks.

Comment: Start by learning C thoroughly, so you really, _really_ understand it.  And using it for a while — maybe 2-5 years.  And then you need to look at language design and compiler design.  And then you need to look at salesmanship and advocacy skills.  And then you'll need to understand the standards-making bureaucracies (plural — per country and ISO as an umbrella).  Etc.  There are lots of extensions in GCC already that are not standard C; the standards committee, for whatever reason, has either not been presented with the feature as a serious standardization proposal or has rejected the feature.

Comment: `struct` is a type, not variable, you cannot assign any value to it. What are you actually looking for is variable initialisation, like `struct qwe foo = {"some_data", NULL}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to mix **definition** with **initialisation** which is not possible in the way you would like to do, at least not in C. To circumvent this limitation functions like

```
Foo* foo_new () {
// alloc and
// do your init code here
}
```

are usually used instead.

---

In i.e. C++ you would use the constructor of your class.

Answer (score 3):

Because a struct is only a definition how memory gets divided. If you define

```
struct a {
    uint8_t a1;
    uint8_t a2;
}
```

This will be 16 bits in memory, and if you access the `a2` member, the compiler translates this to the specific position.

Now, when you allocate that struct using `malloc()`, the malloc gets only the size of the memory it should allocate. It returns a pointer to the first byte of the allocated memory and it doesn't know how this memory is devided into several smaller chunks.

Comment: 16 *bytes*?  Really?  Are you confusing `uint8_t` with `uint64_t`?

Comment: Whop, no: Just bit with byte!

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't have the concept of a constructor. In languages that allow this, the assignment is run as part of object construction.